# React-Router displaying component twice in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am getting a bit confused with the below code in ReactJS Hooks, so basically when i click on Home(http://localhost:3000/)  it is displaying twice (the home component). i cant understand the reason why it is happening.

i have defined the Home and basket component in the Nav component and also under the Router in the App.js, but only basket is showing correctly i.e once only. any suggestions please

Below snippet from App.js file

```
return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="header">
        <Nav userinfo={userData} userstatus={siginalready} />
        

          <Sidebar />
          <Switch>
          <Route
              path="/"
              exact
              render={(props) => (
                <Home
                  {...props}
                  userData={userData}
                  userstatus={siginalready}
                />
              )}
            />
           
            <Route
              path="/basket"
              exact
              render={(props) => (
                <Basket
                  {...props}
                  userData={userData}
                  userstatus={siginalready}
                />
              )}
            />
</Switch>
</Router>)
```

snippet from the Nav.js file

```
 return (
    <nav>
       <label className="logo">
       <Home/>

      </label>

      <ul>
        <li className="searchbar">
        <Search/>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            className="active glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"
            href="./basket"
          ></a>
          <li>
```

snippet from Home.js file

```
function Home() {
  return <div> <a href="/">
  <img src={ProjectLogo} />
  Welcome
</a></div>
}
```

Comment: there is `<Home/>` in your nav file as well as your app.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added `<Home/>` component in your `Nav` component.

When you remove it you will have it rendered only once.

When getting into these kind of problems, inspect element dev tool is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Mario, i will definitively give a try to dev tools.

Comment: Glad i helped. Cheers